# I am getting error when I passed multiple parameter in form-data format in wcf rest api. it is working in Raw data

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

[image: Here you can see my request parameter in Postman.]

Here you can see my request parameter in Postman.

Code as below.

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "/finance")]
        NResultSet FinanceAdd(int StudentID, string SponsorName, string Funds, string FamilyIncome, string Relationship);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you supposed to pass the data in a json format?

Comment: No, its not passed in json format.